# PhoneGap online event and sending data to server

Tags: ajax, cordova

I am making an app where orders are placed. But when the device has no network connection, the orders are to be saved locally on the device until network access is gained again, at which point the data is sent to the server.

I have a concern though. When the device gains connection and the transfer begins, what is stopping the connection failing milliseconds later and ruining the transfer? would it be better to have a function that fires say 10 seconds after having constant network access, or only sending when in a 3G connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loose connection during upload you will also get a failure/error message.
You should provide an error callback and handle what to do.
In case of a succeeding request the entity is removed from local storage - in case of an error it is not removed.